# Windows start command not able to execute batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am executing **start** command from command prompt.
Command calls batch file named **D:\My script.cmd** and passes argument "**Argument one**". Here is command that I am tring to execute.

```
   C:\Users\ABCUser>start "D:\My script.cmd" "Argument one"
```

but getting error mesasge as **The system cannot find the file Argument one.** 
I don't understand why command is searching for file. Contents of file My script.cmd.

```
@echo off
cls
echo "Hello"
echo %1
```

Am I missing something or command syntax is wrong ? This command is not even working for file name without spaces.

Comment: This has nothing to do with `.net` or `c`.  Indeed the file you specify is most likely either just not there, or not accessible to the command prompt where you execute `start` (e.g. permissions).

Comment: I don't have access to a Windows machine at the moment but I suspect it's treating the file as the title of the new process, and the arguments as the file. Try adding an empty string `""` before the file name.

Comment: You don't need `start` here, based on what you've included. You can just use "D:\My script.cmd" "Argument one" without using `start` at all.

Comment: @KenWhite But there is a difference, `start` opens a new task which runs parallel

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the well known bug of start/cmd.exe handling a cmd and also an argument with quotes.
The cause is, that `start` uses cmd.exe /k to start the new task.
The help of cmd /k and cmd /c explains, that in this case the first and last quote are removed.

And additionally you used the start command wrong.

This should work, as the call works like a dummy to supress the quoting problem

```
start "Title" call "D:\My script.cmd" "Argument one"
```

Comment: `call` is wrong. It's for use in the command/batch file itself, to execute other batch or command files. It's not needed here. (The rest is correct, though.)

Comment: @kenwhite You should try it Ken.  jeb is on the ball here.

Comment: @KenWhite First time I saw the `call` trick, I said also that it can't work :-) See my added explanation

Comment: Thanks to all experts here. What "Title" stands for ? Actually I don't need any title. So do I need to keep an empty string in place of "Title" ?

Comment: Yes, an empty double quote is fine.

Comment: @foxidrive:Thanks. Command works with empty string, but it give one additional message as."Not enough storage is available to process this command."
Batch file is just printing 1 string and I don't think requires large memory.

Comment: We can't see your batch file or command - but the syntax above works here when I tested it, with `"title"` or with `""`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cmd.exe /c "D:\My script.cmd" arg1 arg2`

If there is a problem you can switch the /c with /k which will leave the cmd open for you to examin the errors..

gl,

Refael