# "For" with "usebackq" not using back quotes

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a batch file which was working quite happily, until the last couple of runs, and now it's not.
The offending code is as follows:

```
set uncommittedchanges=1
for /f "tokens=* usebackq" %%a in (`"C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git" -C "\my\git\repository" status`) do (
    if "%%a" == "nothing to commit, working directory clean" (
        set uncommittedchanges=0
    )
)
```

And the error I am getting is

> 'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

I'm sure I haven't made any changes to these lines since it was last working, and I can't see anything wrong with the code as it stands.

Can anyone spot what's wrong, or suggest a setting I may have inadvertently changed that affects usebackq?

Comment: Your new cmd is in admin mode ?

Comment: Yes, I've run cmd.exe as administrator.

Comment: I can't answer why you mysteriously went form working to broken, but you might work around the problem by using the 8.3 short alias: `"C:\PROGRA~1\Git\cmd\git" -C "\my\git\repository" status`

Comment: The work around has done it, thank you! I'll go a step further on this, and add C:\Program Files\Git\cmd to my path variable I think...

Comment: `for /F`, when parsing command output, seems to have trouble with command lines starting with `"`, independent on whether or not the `usebackq` option is given (if not, use `'` instead of the back-ticks); you could try the following: `('^""C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git" -C "\my\git\repository" status^"')` (or with back-ticks; there is an additional pair of quotes around the entire command line but escaped to not change the interpretation of the command line)...

Comment: The same can be achieved with `usebackq`: `(\`^""C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git" -C "\my\git\repository" status\`)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bug of the invoking the child cmd.exe instance.
You need to use a workaround to avoid that the first token uses unescaped spaces.

The simplest way is to use `CALL` as it moves your program-token to the second place, and there it works without problems.

```
for /f "tokens=* usebackq" %%a in (`CALL "C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git" -C "\my\git\repository" status`) do (
```

[Windows start command not able to execute batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19276438/463115)